# Accept both an object and a boolean in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm creating this react component that accepts a prop for animations configuration. Ideally, this particular prop should:

- accept a boolean value
- be optional, if it's undefined it will default to true
- accept an object with a specific configuration

The intended result is that whoever uses the component can:

- use it directly, **not specifying the prop**, which would result in a default `true` and subsequent default values under the hood
- use it with said prop set to `false`, which would disable animations altogether
- use it with said prop set to a `custom object`, which enables animations, but changes default values to custom ones

Right now the interface is defined like this (shortened and simplified for understanding sake):

```
animated?: boolean & {property1: type1, ...}
```

Which kinda does what I want, but, when I pass the object as prop, it throws an error unless I specify the type using the `as` keyword.

I was trying to avoid that, so I tried again what I was trying in the beginning and changed the interface to:

```
animated?: {property1: type1, ...} | boolean
```

Which, from what I understand, should mean "Give me a boolean or an object of said type".

The problem is that, using it like this, it throws an error with this format (reason why I changed to the one I'm currently using):

```
Property 'property1' does not exist on type 'boolean | {property1: type1, ...}
...
Property 'property1' does not exist on type 'false'.
```

even though, as you can see, `property1` does exist on that type and I'm not using a boolean.

What's wrong in my reasoning? Is there a better way to achieve the same result? Why is he checking it against `false` in particular and not against `boolean` or the prop's type directly?

Comment: Please give us a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing.  Right now this is mostly just a verbal description of your experience with your IDE, which isn't easy for others to work with.

Comment: That said, it's fairly clear you want `|` and then you need to [narrow the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) before using properties on it if it's an objct. Search for [\[typescript\] property does not exist union](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+property+doesn%27t+exist+union) to find many questions with answers going into the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to narrow the union defined by `animated?: {property1: type1, ...} | boolean`

For example :

```
if(typeof animation === 'boolean') {
  // animated is a bool
} else {
  // animated is an object
  animated.property1 // OK 
}
```